# Create multiple sheets as pdf, endless loop

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote the code below, but I'm still having problems. The code only generates a pdf version of a random sheet. (Fifty times) Also, for some reason, even with the range defined, the code falls into an endless loop. Do you have any suggestion?

````
Dim Folder_path As String
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim filename As String

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
     .Title = "Select the folder path"
     .InitialFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path
     'You must manually add the location; otherwise, it will be the same as workbooks.
     If .Show = -1 Then
        Folder_path = .SelectedItems(1)
     Else
      MsgBox "No selection has been made"
      Exit Sub
     End If
End With

'Processes each worksheet and generates a pdf version of the sheet. Any sheets that are blank will be skipped.
For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For i = 3 To 52
        filename = Worksheets("Master").Cells(i, 1).Value
        
     sh.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, Folder_path & Application.PathSeparator & filename & ".pdf"
     Next i
     'On Error Resume Next
Next

End Sub```
````

Comment: Your `For i = 3 To 52` loop is repeatedly exporting the same sheet using each of the filenames defined in sheet "Master". Is that your intention? Or does each filename in "Master" correspond to a different worksheet in `ThisWorkbook`? If it's the latter, you don't need the `For Each` loop, you can just get each `filename` and then `Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(filename)` and then do your PDF export (assuming there's a direct correspondence between `filename` and sheet name).

Comment: @sigil You are correct; each "Master" filename corresponds to a different worksheet in ThisWorkbook. For instance, the first one to the first sheet, and so forth. Without a looper, how can I get each filename?

Comment: You're getting the filename already with `filename = Worksheets("Master").Cells(i, 1).Value` inside the `For i = 3 to 52` loop, which is fine. What i mean is that you don't have to additionally use the `For Each` loop. Just use the `For i = 3 to 52` loop, and inside of it, set your `sh` variable using the code from my first comment and then call `sh.ExportAsFixedFormat` as the next statement inside that loop.